# Why is typescript unable to find a property in the object?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am using typescript in my project. I am implementing a stripe subscription.

Here is my code:

```
let subscription = event.data.object;
console.log("user subscription:  " + JSON.stringify(subscription));
```

`subscriptions` is showing type `Stripe.Event.Data.Object`.

Here is the console result:

```
user subscription:{ ........... , expires_at:"16244565", .........}
```

Now I try to extract the value of `expires_at` from `subscription`.

Here is the code:

```
let subscription = event.data.object;
console.log("user subscription:  " + JSON.stringify(subscription)); 
console.log("due date:  " + subscription.expires_at);
```

Now I see that a wiggly red line appears below `.expires_at` and says `Property 'expires_at' does not exist on type 'Object'`. But when I console `subscription` I could see a field `expires_at`.

Please guide me on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using TypeScript you should create types for your values. I think they can be found in Stripe API documentation https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions.

```
type SubscriptionResponseParams = {
...
expires_at: string;
}

let subscription: SubscriptionParams = ...
```

It would probably generate another error, if so, you have to map that event to your subscription response.